# Return to my home country after visa expires, but leaving foreign country in time. OK?

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, novice-travellers

In my case, my home country is India, and I return to India from Germany. My Visa expires a day before I reach my home country. I leave the foreign country within the Visa valid period. Is there going to be a problem?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

Your own country cannot refuse to admit you, and it is none of their business whether any foreign visas you have are valid. You are Indian, so you have an absolute right to enter India, **period!**

So no, there will be no problems, so long as your passport is valid.

Comment: I think the OP's concern is probably with making sure  the country he visited has record of his leaving before the visa expired (doesn't want an overstay record) and in his case there is nothing to worry about since Germany has exit controls.

Comment: "so long as your passport is valid." - I think even this isn't always the case, e.g. if you're Polish you can enter Poland with expired passport. Unless by "valid" you mean "original and issued by your country".

Comment: @Kuba India requires their own passports to be valid. Of course they can't refuse a citizen entry, but they can delay and possibly fine them

Comment: @Crazydre ok, I didn't know :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights---more/transfer.detail.suffix.html/article/flights-and-more/checks/passport-and-id-checks.html) page on Frankfurt Airport:

> If you are traveling to a country outside the Schengen Zone or you are not a citizen of an EU country, you will be checked when leaving Germany. You may be required to show that you have a visa.

If that is correct, and the German immigration checks your visa, you should get an exit stamp, assuming you are leaving directly from Germany to India.

If they don't for some reason you should be able to request a stamp- Germany requires that you [declare cash](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Leaving-Germany/leaving_germany_node.html;jsessionid=16A9A181C930A069C0999C52F7AF55A8.live4672) in excess of EUR 10K on exit, for example, so there must be a customs and immigration station available.

Comment: ...directly from Germany to India or any other non-Schengen destination, of course.